# How to code prerequisites into an MSI?

Tags: windows-installer, prerequisites

Is it possible to code prerequisite conditions into an `MSI`?

eg. if I need my `MSI` package to have `Java JRE`, `.NET 3.5` etc installed as well, is it possible for the `MSI` to know that these other installations are required as well?

Comment: Pretty sure that you need a bootstrapper that checks if the prerequisites are installed, and if not, installs them before your app. Have you checked the documentation or tried anything to get this to work?

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to use a bootstrapper/chainer to install the pre-requisites. The WiX toolset comes with a very powerful bootstrapper/chainer called Burn. You can access it via the `Bundle` element.